# Missing Carrier / Battery bar in Phonegap IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working on my first Phonegap IOS App. My problem is that there is no static background behind the carrier and battery. My app seems (when running) to replace the bar background completely. I hope I am explaining this correctly.
How do I get the background of the Carrier / battery bar to remain and push my app down a little?
I am using  Jquery Mobile if thats any help.

This is what I currently have in the ModelViewController:

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandQueue.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
@end

@interface MainCommandDelegate : CDVCommandDelegateImpl
@end

@interface MainCommandQueue : CDVCommandQueue
@end
```

Comment: you are running your app on iOS7 and your view goes behind your status bar? yes?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thats exactly what happens

Comment: I tried the same with Android and did not have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code in your MainViewController.h

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 // View defaults to full size. If you want to customize the view's size, or its          subviews (e.g. webView),
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 // you can do so here.
 //Lower screen 20px on ios 7
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
 {
     CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
     viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
     viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height-20;
     self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, will give it a try tonight. Thanks

Comment: Hi the1pawan - Where exactly do I need to add it? I added it to the bottom and got an error.

Comment: the1pawan, I added what I currently have in the MainViewController.h, above.

Comment: @user2110655 add in MainViewController.m and let me know if you have problem

Comment: Hi the1pawan
I got it working, thanks. But now I have one more problem. I have a banner right at the bottom of the page and now that's being cut in half.

Comment: @user2110655 what is banner frame you have set